# Set Null value on Dbfield

Tags: c#, sitecore, nunit

```
  public void Testing_Code()
    {
        var implementationTypeId = Sitecore.Data.ID.NewID;
        using (Sitecore.FakeDb.Db db = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Db
        {
           new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("TestingInstanceItem")
            {
              new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbField(Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName){ Value=null }     
        })
     ......................
```

In the above testing code I have assigned the countryName field to Null.But when Executing it takes the null value as Empty String.On the repository where it is referenced ,

```
testingModel.countryName= testingModelItem.Fields[Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName] != null ?
                                                    testingModelItem.Fields[Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName].Value : string.Empty;
```

The following line should be false .but it is showing true

```
testingModelItem.Fields[Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName] != null
```

Comment: try instead of `Value=null` use `DBNull.Value` and also replace the test against null with `DBNull.Value`

Comment: thanks @styx, can you explain how to write in details. I'm beginner here!.I mean how to set the null value to the template.

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbField(Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName){ Value=null }
```

with this

```
new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbField(Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName){ Value=DBNull.Value }
```

and instead of != null (for each test against the DB)
do

```
if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(testingModelItem.Fields[Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName])) 
     {
      //not null
      }
      else
      {
      //null
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code you posted does return a *field* rather than a *value* (an instance of `Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field` class instead of a `string`):

```
testingModelItem.Fields[Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName]
```

It can be `null` only if there is no such a field in a template. If you want to get a *field value*, you should use

```
testingModelItem.Fields[Templates.sampleTemplates.Fields.countryName]?.Value
```

Secondary, it's impossible to get `null` value from a field (at least for 8.0+). It was possible for (very) old versions but now `Value` property replaces `null`s with empty strings:

```
public string Value
{
  get
  {
    return this.GetValue(true, true) ?? string.Empty;
  }
  ...
}
```